# Virtual Machine Custom Script Extension not downloading file from Azure Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

Trying to use "CustomScriptExtension" on Azure Virtual Machine but it returns following error:

```
Failed to download all specified files. Exiting. Error Message: CustomScript failed to download the blob https://test.blob.core.windows.net/test/Test.ps1 because the server returned a response of \\\"**The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict. Public access is not permitted on this storage account**.
```

Here are the steps followed:

1. Created VM and assigned its managed identity.
2. Created storage account and provided following role based access to managed identity

   Storage Account Contributor

   Storage Blob Data Reader
3. Created a simple powershell script and uploaded to storage container blob.
4. Created a bicep template

```
param arcMachineName string = 'TestServer'
param location string = resourceGroup().location
resource customscriptextension 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions@2022-03-01' = {  
  name: '${arcMachineName}/customScriptExtension'
  location: location
  properties: {
    publisher: 'Microsoft.Compute'
    type: 'CustomScriptExtension'
    typeHandlerVersion: '1.10'
    autoUpgradeMinorVersion: true
    settings: {
      fileUris: [
        'https://test.blob.core.windows.net/test/Test.ps1'
      ]
      commandToExecute: 'powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ${scriptFileName}'
      managedIdentity : []
    }
  }
}
```

5. Running bicep using following:

   `az deployment group create --resource-group "test-rg" --template-file "test.bicep"`

Can someone please tell me what am I missing here ?

Comment: Can you check with access permissions for the storage account blob where your PowerShell script is located and retry? @DevHelp

Comment: Pls let me know where to look for ?

Answer (score 1):

> I tried Verifying and Troubleshooting Azure VM Custom Script Extension Deployment using the requirement mentioned and I was able provision successfully

The error message you are encountering, **"The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict. Public access is not permitted on this storage account"**, indicates a permissions issue related to accessing the blob storage.

[image]

**My Blob file container inside storage account**

[image]

1. **Managed Identity Permissions**: To access the storage blob, the VM's managed identity must have the roles of 'Storage Account Contributor' and 'Storage Blob Data Reader', as you have assigned. Verify that the VM and the managed identity are correctly linked and that the managed identity has the required permissions.
   .
2. **Storage Account Access Level**: The error suggests that the storage account does not allow public access. This is generally a good security practice, but it means that any access must be explicitly granted. Ensure that the managed identity has access to the specific container and blob.
3. **Blob URL**: Check if the URL `https://test.blob.core.windows.net/test/Test.ps1` is correct. The blob must be in the specified container and the URL must be accurately pointing to it

**Prerequisites resources before running the deployment command.**

[image]

**My `test.bicep` file:**

```
// test.bicep
// This template deploys a Custom Script Extension to an Azure VM.

param vmName string = 'testvmvkserver'
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param scriptFileUri string = 'https://demovksbtest.blob.core.windows.net/test/Test.ps1'

resource customScriptExtension 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions@2022-03-01' = {
  name: '${vmName}/customScriptExtension'
  location: location
  properties: {
    publisher: 'Microsoft.Compute'
    type: 'CustomScriptExtension'
    typeHandlerVersion: '1.10'
    autoUpgradeMinorVersion: true
    settings: {
      fileUris: [
        scriptFileUri
      ]
      commandToExecute: 'powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File Test.ps1'
    }
  }
}
```

**My demo `Test.ps1` file:**

```
# Test.ps1
# This script simply outputs the date and a list of running processes.

# Output the current date and time
Write-Output "Current Date and Time:"
Get-Date

# Output a list of running processes
Write-Output "List of Running Processes:"
Get-Process | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Now run the **deployment group** creation command

```
az deployment group create --resource-group "testvk-rg" --template-file "test.bicep"
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: followed exact same steps and still had same issue. One difference is that the storage account configuration is set to not allowed public access.

Comment: please provide access to have anonymous privilege to user on blob and storage so that you will not get the error you mentioned